# What is the Qt 'way' for using an external executable as a pipe?

Tags: c++, qt, process, pipe, qt5

I have a GUI application using Qt framework and another one that just processes some text from `stdin` and displays its output in `stdout`.

How do I portably use this second executable from the Qt application ?
The user of the main application will create the data that needs to be processed.
(The result is to be displayed back to the user)

The second application can not know/depend on anything of the main application, so developing a server like abstraction is out of the question.

I do not want to write Linux specific code for this as the application needs to run on other platforms in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QProcess` to start the second application, provide the input and read its output :

```
QProcess process;
process.start("secondApp");
process.waitForStarted();

process.write(input, count);
process.closeWriteChannel();

process.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output;
output = process.readAllStandardOutput();
```

Comment: It seems to work, but the process is not returning after the string ends.
How do I write an EOF to it ?